# Adding a form at the end of the content

Tags: plugins, hooks, the-content

I'm trying to add a little form after each post for a plugin I have to code, but I'm not very familiar with Wordpress. By using add_action with the_content as hook, I was able to add some text to the content.

My trouble is that the whole text stored in the $content variable seemed to be processed somehow. Specifically, there is a br/ added after each of my input fields, which break the layout of my form. I noticed that I don't have this issue if I had my form right before the comment form, for instance. But I don't want to put my form here, I need it to be really just after the post itself, prior to anything related to comments.

Is there a way to disable this text and html formatting, but only for the form I'll be adding to the content ? In case there is no easy way to do so, I've tried finding a hook that would allow me to add something AFTER the content and BEFORE the comments to do so, but had no luck finding one. Is there such a hook ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are doing, and the problem you are having, the first thing I'd try is to [add your `the_content` filter with a large priority number](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) so that it runs late, and hopefully after the other formatting filters.

`add_filter('the_content','your_callback',100);`

If that doesn't do it you may have to remove and reorder some some filters.

If this is a page and you can edit the template for that page, you could also run [`get_the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content), apply the content filters to it, then append your form before you `echo`.

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters('the_content',$content);
$content = $content.$your_form;
echo $content;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll actually want to `filter` the content, not use an action. You could wrap your form in the output buffer and append it onto to it, like so:

```
function my_content_filter($content) {
    ob_start(); 

    // your form here

    $form = ob_get_clean();

    if (get_post_type() == 'post')
        return $content . $form;

    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'my_content_filter');
```

Let me know if that helps.