# Add hook after content without formatting

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, filters, hooks, the-content

I want to add a table after the_content with a hook, but it's adding `<p>` tags in certain areas. This is a plugin, I don't want to remove `<p>` tags from all the_content, just the table I'm trying to add.

Here's an example, but my table is bigger and inside it's adding p tags in different spots.

```php
function addTable( $content ) {
  $table = '<table><tbody><tr><td>Example html here</td></tr></tbody></table>';

  $content .= $table;

  return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'addTable', 20 );
```

Someone asked this in 2012, no answer but I'm trying to do the same thing:
[Adding a form at the end of the content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74453/adding-a-form-at-the-end-of-the-content)

I do **not** want to remove `<p>` tags from a theme's entire blog post, only the content I am appending. In this case, I'm appending a table.

Is there a way to disable the formatting for only the content I'm appending? Otherwise, how is it possible in WordPress to attach a form or table to a post with hooks without it adding formatting?

Comment: unrelated to your problem, but there is a mistake in the `add_filter` call, `addTable` should be `"addTable"`

Comment: wpautop is added with a priority of 10, but you're adding your table with a priority of 20 which happens afterwards. Are you finding the p tags via the dev tools? Or have you inspected the raw view-source version and found them there too? Is your example able to reproduce the issue as is? Or would modifications be needed to reproduce the issue, aka changing the Example html here part?

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks I updated my question. I think I tried 10 already, but I'll try different numbers, not sure if that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Pull from the provided answer back in 2012 and testing with the 2021 theme it works as intended.

```
function addTable( $content ) {
        
        ob_start(); 
        echo '<table><tbody><tr><td>Example html here</td></tr></tbody></table>';
        $table = ob_get_clean();
        
        $content .= $table;
      
        return $content;
    }
      
    add_filter( 'the_content', "addTable", 20 );
```

[image]

Comment: this is functionally equivalent to what the OP posted, output buffers do nothing to help here other than making the creation of `$table` more complicated. I agree that `addTable` needed to be wrapped in quotes though

Comment: Correct, I just used one of the examples from the included link that was stated to work. I could not get it to add p tags regardless of how large I made the table.